# error: Invalid value for blake2_256_digest. Error: Use a valid, hex-encoded, BLAKE2 message digest, when uploading packget to pypi?

Tags: python, pypi

I want to upload my packaget to pypi.

in the last step:

```
python setup.py sdist upload
```

i met:

```
Invalid value for blake2_256_digest. Error: Use a valid, hex-encoded, BLAKE2 message digest
```

i am confused on this error, can anyone help on this?

Answer (score -1):

According to [Christian Heimes on the Python bug tracker](https://bugs.python.org/issue45590#msg404905):

> Distutils is deprecated and should no longer be used. Please use twine to upload software to PyPI, https://blog.ganssle.io/articles/2021/10/setup-py-deprecated.html